# How to debug computer not shutting down issue on 21.04?

Tags: shutdown, 21.04

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 21.04, and I am using the default kernel, 5.11.0-16-generic.
I am also using the Nvidia driver (nvidia-driver-460, version 460.73.01-0ubuntu1) with XOrg.

When I shut down, my laptop never actually shuts down.

How can I debug this issue?

When I shutdown, I usually see a black screen and the laptop stays on and the fans spin up. (A couple of times I saw the (plymouth?) shutdown splash screen which just froze).

I then have to hold the power button to shut down the device.

I suspect it is a process that is not stopping or failure during the shut down process.

I tried executing

```
journalctl -rb -1
```

But there is too much information, and I can't find the spot where the machine is supposed to shutdown.

Is there something I could look for in `journalctl`, or a better way to find out what is causing this behavior?

---

**UPDATE 1**

I created a bug report, [Computer does not shut down](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1926816), against the gdm3 package. If anyone else is experiencing this issue, please mark yourself as impacted for this bug report.

**UPDATE 2**

The GDM error in my journalctl log was not the cause of this shutdown problem. I've closed the above referenced bug.

I did figure out a [work-around, posted in the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1926816/comments/5), if anyone is also experiencing this issue.

Comment: I have noticed that all messages may not appear in `journalctl`.  Maybe configure GRUB to watch shutdown messages.

Comment: Do your shutdown command, then wait 35 minutes. There are some 30 minute timeouts.In a terminal window, the command `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. Check for "timeout" messages.

Comment: You may want to report as a bug. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en\

Comment: @waltinator, your `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` is quite useful. I'll run this on each reboot to see if I can find something unusual in the logs. (So far I've see the "timeout" message on snapd, but I'll try to verify with more tests). @David, I'll open a bug report if I can identify something more specific for the developers to work with and fix.

Comment: @waltinator, please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it. You have provided the correct options to the `journalctl` command, which shows me everything before the journaling stopped during the last shutdown.

Comment: I was never able to find the cause even after examining numerous shut-down logs using `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`. However, this issue has now gone away with the upgrade to kernel 5.11.0-18-generic. (Note that this kernel upgrade coincided with an upgrade of the Nvidia driver to version 460.80-0ubuntu0.21.04.2. So that may have contributed to the fix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your shutdown command, then wait 35 minutes. There are some 30 minute timeouts.In a terminal window, the command `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. Check for "timeout" messages.

Comment: This is very good advice.  I learned a lot about the error from just letting it run for a long time.