# Black Screen on fresh install of Ubuntu 21.04 can't turn laptop off

Tags: system-installation, suspend, lenovo, battery, 21.04

I just did a fresh install Ubuntu 21.04 on my laptop, Lenovo Ideapad 5 14ARE05 with AMD Ryzen 7 4700U CPU. Installed some programs, put it on Suspend from the menu. A few hours later, when I come back to it I see that it's turned on, hearing the fans and the turned on illuminated keyboard. But the screen is off, the monitor connected to it doesn't get a signal from the laptop and it doesn't respond to the power button, keyboard buttons (besides the combination to turn on or off keyboard illumination) or by moving the mouse. Anyone has any idea how to get it out of this state? It has internal battery that I cannot remove manually and it will last more than half, or maybe a full day if I let it to discharge on its on, having the screen turned off for some reason...Had no problems with the laptop until now with Windows 10 or Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: I have seen a lot of issues like this with 21.04... Maybe the Beta release is not yet entirely stable? I would recommend installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to be able to have all of the security possible. You can turn off your laptop by disconnecting the battery from the device. Leave it off for ten seconds, and retry power on on Ubuntu 21.04, if you do not want to use 20.04 LTS. If that does not work, I would suggest the first suggestion that I made.

Comment: I see your point about 21.04 not being stable and I'm planning on installing something else after I get it to work, but for now I can't turn off the laptop or interact with it in any way possible by keyboard or mouse/touchpad to be able to install something else.

Comment: You can remove the battery with a screwdriver. 1. Grab your screwdriver and remove back panel (since your computer is stuck on, I would suggest being very careful). 2. Locate li-ion battery (bottom left-hand corner) and unplug cables from motherboard (again, be very careful. Don't touch your motherboard directly, could potentially fry it)

Comment: If the problem can be reliably repeated on your hardware using a 21.04 LiveUSB (to provide a stock environment), then please file a proper bug report for the apparent reversion.

Comment: Ubuntu had always problems with hybernation / suspend. But, for such cases you can always press the power button and keep it pressed for several seconds until its power goes off. This method should be available in any laptop, tablet or mobile phone afaik. Also, did you try to press Ctrl+Alt+F4 (or F5) to see if you can get a text based login prompt?

Comment: I have been experiencing this issue when I attempt to shutdown the computer. Here is a suggestion on how to find / debug the cause: https://askubuntu.com/q/1333722/100356. I haven't been able to identify the cause from my logs, but you may have better luck.

Comment: After keeping pressed the power button for some seconds I was able to turn off the laptop, thanks a lot for the help. I repeated the problem using a 21.04 LiveUSB and it appeared after clicking on the Suspend button in the menu, the screen turned off, but the laptop stayed on (fans working, keyboard light turned on), pressing the keyboard or the mouse didn't get the laptop to work, when plugged in, the power button doesn't work, but when unplugged from the charger the power button works to turn off the laptop. How can I "file a proper bug report for the apparent reversion"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Add `acpi=force` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

   For example,

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=nouveau acpi=force"
   ```
3. Save the file.

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Update grub.

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot to make the changes effective.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't resolve the Suspend problem.