# Ubuntu UI screen image freezes randomly during usage after fresh 21.04 install, suspecting Wayland or Nouveau

Tags: freeze, wayland, nouveau, 21.04

Edit: reported this at:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wayland/+bug/1931387 as well, and it was found to be a duplicate of: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdrm/+bug/1497593

I was running 20.10 previously with NVIDIA drivers,

Then four days ago, I did a clean 21.04 install from ISO without installing the NVIDIA drivers, and since then the UI has frozen three times on me.

I am unable to determine exactly what action triggered the freezes, I was just basically using Chromium browser normally in most/all cases.

The third time, I was just looking at a webpage, I wasn't even touching my mouse at that exact moment, and then it just froze.

I am then unable to see anything move on the screen, including after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, the last image just stays fixed.

The third time was also a bit different.

A few seconds after freezing, it actually went down to a black terminal screen as during boot messages:

[image]

and then I was redirected to the login screen, as if I had been logged out.

I was able to login, my programs were closed, so I was effectively logged out.

Then two Apport windows showed up, and one of them contained several references to Xwayland. Under `/var/crash/_usr_bin_Xwayland.1000.crash` I see one of them:

- `ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -noreset -accessx -core -auth /run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.48ZQ40 -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6 -initfd 7`
- `StackTraceAddressSignature` contained mentions of Xwayland and nouveau_dri.so:

  ```
  StacktraceAddressSignature: /usr/bin/Xwayland:6:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.33.so+864:/usr/bin/Xwayland+13cb40:/usr/bin/Xwayland+14866f:/usr/bin/Xwayland+13b1a7:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.33.so+864:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.33.so+749:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.33.so+123d6:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0+25d7:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0+2537:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0+265f:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0+2a77:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0+31aa:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so+93b943:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so+93bc61:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so+17cc01
  ```

I also checked and I am using Wayland (the default since 21.04 apparently): [How can I tell if I am running Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904940/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-running-wayland/1344287#1344287)

Hardware:

- Lenovo ThinkPad P51
- NVIDIA Quadro M1200 4GB GDDR5 GPU

Just after the crash, dmesg contained the following possibly interesting lines:

```
[ 9556.450894] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 3 [00ff8cf000 Xwayland[3831]]
[ 9556.450907] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC2/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 3c000d [OOR_REG]
[ 9556.454264] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 3 [00ff8cf000 Xwayland[3831]]
[ 9556.454283] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC0/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 3e000d [OOR_REG]
[ 9556.466339] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 3 [00ff8cf000 Xwayland[3831]]
[ 9556.466351] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC3/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 3e000d [OOR_REG]
[ 9698.230726] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xwayland[3831]: failed to idle channel 5 [Xwayland[3831]]
[ 9713.230743] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xwayland[3831]: failed to idle channel 5 [Xwayland[3831]]
[ 9713.231918] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000000056000 engine 07 [HOST0] client 06 [HUB/HOST] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 5 [00ff0d9000 Xwayland[3831]]
[ 9713.231930] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 5: killed
[ 9713.231932] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
[ 9713.231939] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 5: scheduled for recovery
[ 9713.231943] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xwayland[3831]: channel 5 killed!
[ 9717.642691] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
[ 9717.642702] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
[ 9717.642709] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 3: killed
[ 9717.642714] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
[ 9717.643113] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xwayland[3831]: channel 3 killed!
[ 9719.351714] apport-gtk[119654]: segfault at 18 ip 00007f337637d194 sp 00007ffd95094dc0 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2404.21[7f3376274000+385000]
[ 9719.351721] Code: c4 08 5b 5d c3 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8b 7f 10 48 85 ff 74 0b e9 ce c6 ff ff 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 83 ec 08 48 89 d7 e8 0c 36 17 00 <48> 8b 40 18 48 8b 78 10 e8 ef 03 09 00 48 83 c4 08 48 89 c7 e9 a3
[ 9744.187533] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 9745.940823] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 9775.737572] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 9777.953055] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

Related:

- [Ubuntu 21.04 Wayland, GIMP black window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334177/ubuntu-21-04-wayland-gimp-black-window) GIMP works fine
- [Blackscreen - failed to idle channel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600467/blackscreen-failed-to-idle-channel) contains one of the key dmesg messages I saw similar to "Xwayland[3831]: channel 5 killed!"

Fuller logs at: https://gist.github.com/cirosantilli/f679b17f5e18253036bf58fc3ff8690d

Comment: I am facing the same issue with my new PC `AMD® Ryzen 7 3700x 8-core processor × 16 `, `NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)`, `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit`, `GNOME Version 3.36.8`, `Windowing System X11`

Comment: Here is the kernel log https://gist.github.com/amitpatelx/840e3673ab600c60032106c7f7ad2440